# Question on reverse union bound for independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, concentration-of-measure

From the note [on union bound](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nickhar/F18-531/NotesHoeffding.pdf) I found the following

> **Fact 1.3** (Reverse Union Bound) Let $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ be arbitrary events, not necessarily independent. Suppose that $\operatorname{Pr}[\mathcal{F}_1]\geq 1-p_1$ and $\operatorname{Pr}[\mathcal{F}_2]\geq 1-p_2$. Then $\operatorname{Pr}[\mathcal{F}_1 \cap \mathcal{F}_2]\geq 1-(p_1+p_2)$.

Here if $\mathcal{F}_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ were known to be independent, does that imply the following?

$$\operatorname{Pr}[\mathcal{F}_1 \cap \mathcal{F}_2] \geq (1-p_1)(1-p_2)$$

Comment: Yes, of course. Because $P(F_1\cap F_2)=P(F_1)P(F_2)$ and $1-p_1\geq 0$ and $1-p_2\geq 0$

Comment: Or simply that the product $(1-p_1)(1-p_2)$ is greater than *or equal to* itself.

Comment: Your use of $\mathcal F$ for an event is confusing. Typically the ***mathcal*** command is reserved for $\sigma$-algebras, not their elements (which we call "events").